# How can I sort a big text file with Dask?

Tags: dask

I have a text file which is way bigger than my memory. I want to sort the lines of that file lexicographically. I know how to do it manually:

1. Split into chunks which fit into memory
2. Sort the chunks
3. Merge the chunks

I wanted to do it with dask. I thought dealing with big amounts of data would be one use case of dask. How can I sort the whole data with Dask?

### My Try

You can execute [generate_numbers.py -n 550_000_000](https://github.com/MartinThoma/algorithms/blob/master/sorting/generate_numbers.py) which will take about 30 minutes and generate a 20 GB file.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

filename = "numbers-large.txt"

print("Create ddf")
ddf = dd.read_csv(filename, sep = ',', header = None).set_index(0)

print("Compute ddf and sort")
df = ddf.compute().sort_values(0)

print("Write")
with open("numbers-large-sorted-dask.txt", "w") as fp:
    for number in df.index.to_list():
        fp.write(f"{number}\n")
```

when I execute this, I get

```
Create ddf
Compute ddf and sort
[2]    2437 killed     python dask-sort.py
```

I guess the process is killed because it consumes too much memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd

inpFn = "numbers-large.txt"
outFn = "numbers-large-sorted-dask.txt"
blkSize = 500   # For test on a small file - increase it

print("Create ddf")
ddf = dd.read_csv(inpFn, header = None, blocksize=blkSize)

print("Sort")
ddf_sorted = ddf.set_index(0)

print("Write")
fut = ddf_sorted.to_csv(outFn, compute=False, single_file=True, header=None)
dask.compute(fut)
print("Stop")
```

Note that I set so low `blkSize` parameter just for test purpose.
In the target version either increase its value or drop, along with
`blocksize=blkSize`, to accept the default value.

As `set_index` provides the sort, there is no need to call `sort_values()`
and other detail is that *dask* does not support this method.

As far as writing is concerned, I noticed that you want to generate a
**single** output file, instead of a **sequence** of files (one file for each
partition), so I passed `single_file=True`.

I also added `header=None` to block writing the column name, in this
case (not very meaningful) **0**.

The last detail to mention is `compute=False`, so that *dask*
generates a sequence of *future* objects, without executing them
(computing it) - for now.

All operations so far only constructed the computation tree,
without its execution.
As late as now, *compute(...)* runs the whole computation tree.

## Edit

Your code probably failed due to:

```
df = ddf.compute().sort_values(0)
```

Note that you:

- first *compute()*, to generate the whole *pandasonic* DataFrame,
- after that, at the *Pandas* level, you attempt to sort it.

The problem is probably that the memory in your computer is not
big enough to hold the whole result of *compute()*.
So most likely your code failed just at this moment, without any
chance to sort this DataFrame.

Comment: I will later try it with a smaller file, but with the 20GB file I interrupted the execution after more than 5 hours. With Bash (split + sort) it takes ~24 minutes to sort that file.

Comment: Check also this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46971219/dask-set-index-from-large-unordered-csv-file